# 17.04 Firefox loads but can not server

Tags: firefox, 17.04

I just loaded 17.04 on an IBM Thinkpad. The Thinkpad loads onto the web, but Firefox can not find the server.

Comment: What site are you trying to connect to? Can anything else in the computer communicate to the internet? Can anything else communicate to that server?

Comment: The Thinkpad says it is on the net. When Firefox loads up it says it can not find the server. Input an address and it says the same.